# print result was truncated in databricks notebook

Tags: printing, databricks, truncated

To get schema in JSON format, I used "print(df.schema.json())" command. The schema was too large and was truncated.
Is there any way to show it all?

Comment: Hi @Sean Fu, please consider adding some more examples of your code. It is preferable to add a minimal reproducible code example so we can further help you.

Answer (score 0):

No, there is a limit on maximum size of the output in the notebook cell. If you need to store your schema, output it into the file on the DBFS, and then copy file to local machine, for example, by using [databricks-cli](https://docs.databricks.com/data/databricks-file-system.html#databricks-cli):

```py
with open("/dbfs/FileStore/my-schema.json", "w") as f:
  f.write(df.schema.json())
```